# Calculate average within category

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to calculate the average of a measure within a category?

For example, in my data model, I have a table "Geo" that contains the field "País" (Country).

In table "Clientes" I have the field "Cliente" (Customer).

This is how the relationship looks like:

[image]

The facts table is "Vendas".

I need the average of measure "Margem Líquida *" per country, so I'm using the following measure:

```
Margem Média País = AVERAGEX(Clientes;[Margem Líquida *])
```

This is ok on a Country level, but as you can see in the following table I can't compare the value of the measure with the average per country on a Customer ("Cliente") level.

[image]

I'd like to have the value of the country level repeated for each customer within the country.

How can I do that? I've tried all sorts of `CALCULATE` with `EARLIER` but no luck...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So for Australia, you want the 53.907 in the right column for all four clients in that country?

Comment: Hello, that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if either of these work for you:

```
Margem Média País = AVERAGEX(ALL(Clientes[Cliente]); [Margem Líquida *])

Margem Média País = CALCULATE(
                        AVERAGEX(Clientes; [Margem Líquida *]);
                        ALL(Clientes[Cliente]))
```

If not, then please post a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your data.

---

**Edit:** Something like this might help with the issue you mentioned in your comment.

```
Margem Média País = CALCULATE(
                        AVERAGEX(Clientes; [Margem Líquida *]);
                        ALL(Clientes),
                        Geo[País] IN VALUES(Geo[País]))
```

Comment: Thanks, they both return the correct value, although they show values for all customers (even if they don't belong to the respective country). I know I can fix this with an IF but isn't there a better way?

Comment: Try my edit. There should be a way, but it's hard to write DAX without sample data to test on.

Comment: This is brilliant, even without seeing the data, thank you so much!